# Problem closing Excel exported from SAP GUI with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I run a macro which download an Excel report from SAP GUI, save it, and then I need the Excel to be closed. I read similar post in this page but none of them solves my issue.

The problem is that once the Macro finish, the Excel downloaded from SAP GUI automatically opens. Is like the Excel is running in the background.
So, if I close it during the macro, the code won't find the open Excel (which make sense since the excel is not opened yet) and gives error.. BUT when the macro finish the excel appears (that's because of SAP software behavior, that when you download an Spreadsheet the Excel opens automatically. I have tried changing SAP configuration but didn't get lucky)

I tried put `Application.Wait`, `Workbook.Close`, kill the workbook (which it gives a problem because a pop up shows telling that the workbook does not exist), call another sub, etc.

I tried a solution that I read in this page which is add the `wshell` part but doesn't work in my code.

VBA code in `TestExcel.xlsm`:

```
        Sub test

        'Sap conection

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nzv04hn"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VKORG-LOW").Text = "CR01"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUART-LOW").Text = "zor"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_PGI").SetFocus
        session.findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 8
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
        session.findById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 43
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\"
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "CR01ZV04HN.XLSX"
        session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 4
        session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[7]").press
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        Set Wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Wshell.Run "C:\Users\Desktop\xxx\SAP_Workbook_Close.vbs", 1, False
        End sub
```

VBScript code in `SAP_Workbook_Close.vbs`:

```
SAP_Workbook = "CR01ZV04HN.XLSX" 
on error resume next
do
err.clear
Set xclApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number = 0 Then exit do
'msgbox "Wait for Excel session"
wscript.sleep 2000
loop

do 
err.clear
Set xclwbk = xclApp.Workbooks.Item(SAP_Workbook)
If Err.Number = 0 Then exit do
'msgbox "Wait for SAP workbook"
wscript.sleep 2000
loop

on error goto 0 
Set xclSheet = xclwbk.Worksheets(1)

xclApp.Visible = True
xclapp.DisplayAlerts = false

xclapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close


Set xclwbk = Nothing
Set xclsheet = Nothing
'xclapp.Quit
set xclapp = Nothing
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try this in your original workbook: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False : Application.Quit`

Comment: It Does not work

Comment: May Try `xclapp.Quit` after  line `xclapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close`

Comment: To see how far your program comes, please activate the following commands in the script: msgbox "Wait for Excel session" and msgbox "Wait for SAP workbook"

Comment: What happens if you explicitly open the workbook in your code and the close it?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for solution to close excel files that are opened automatically by SAP after exporting. here is my solution.
SAP exports excel in other Excel instances ( sometimes it creates 2 or 3 other instances). So just calling Workbooks("name.xlsx").close wont work.

here is my program to close all excel files opened by SAP.
Suppose my macro program is written in "Acetate.xlsm", and SAP generated 3 excel files named a.xlsx, b.xlsx, c.xlsx

```
Sub Close_excel()
    Dim xlApp as Object
    Dim filepath as String
    Dim wb_name as String
    Dim i as Long
'define absolute path to excel files opened by SAP
file_path = Array("....\a.xlsx", "....\b.xlsx", ".....\c.xlsx")
wb_name = Array("a.xlsx", "b.xlsx", "c.xlsx")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
For i = LBound(file_path) to UBound(file_path) do
    Set xlApp = GetObject(filepath(i)).Application
    
   'Avoid closing "Acetate.xlsm" which contains this macro
    If xlApp.Workbooks(wb_name(i)).Name <> "Acetate" then 
       xlApp.Workbooks(wb_name(i)).Close True
       Set xlApp = Nothing
    End If
    Next i
  End Sub
```